# In LibreOffice impress, how can I have a bullet-indentation no-bullet item?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I want to do something like the following in LibreOffice Impress:

- First item
- Second item start

  - first subitem of second item
  - second subitem of second item

  continuation of the second item.

the "continuation of the second item" is indented the same as the first line of the second item, but it's essentially a second paragraph (I wouldn't mind a nested subitems mechanism, but LO Impress doesn't work that way) with an indentation.

How can I achieve this? If I "Increase Indent", then the whole text box - all items - get indented.

Note: Using LibreOffice 7.0.

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdkEv.png) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's just the thing.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as the accepted answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

- Add another bullet point with the same indentation than "Second item start". This can be done by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of "Second item start". Type at least one word.
- Put the cursor at the beginning of the first word of the newly added bullet point, press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the bullet point. The indentation will remain although the bullet point has been deleted. You can cut and paste the paragraph to another.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the start of the line you wish to start the indented bullet points, by using your mouse or your keyboard arrow keys, or press the home key to go to the start of the line. Now muster up your courage, and prepare thyself, mentally commit to the process, and press the `TAB` key on your keyboard. The line will be indented to the right. `Shift + TAB` will unindent by one depth.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please [edit] and expand upon what you mean, else your answer may be deleted due to its brevity.

Comment: @Greenoline, which part is not clear? The answer is very simple and brief. If someone said how do you insert a new line, and the answer was press the enter key, that would also be classified as too brief.